# Scala: buggy type inference?

Tags: scala, type-inference

The following is a simplified version of my original code to make things simpler (sorry it's still a bit complicated):

```
trait BuilderBase
trait MessageBase {
  type Builder <: BuilderBase
}
class SomeMessage extends MessageBase {
  type Builder = SomeMessage.Builder
}
object SomeMessage {
  class Builder extends BuilderBase
}
class Covariant[+T]
class NonCovariant[T]
def func[T <: MessageBase](value: Covariant[T]): Covariant[T#Builder] = null

val message: Covariant[SomeMessage] = null
val result: Covariant[SomeMessage.Builder] = func(message)
```

And the last line fails to compile with an error at `func(→ message ← here)`:

> type mismatch; found : Covariant[SomeMessage] required: Covariant[SomeMessage.type]

Definitely func takes parameter of Covariant of T that is subclass of MessageBase, what's required there is Covariant[SomeMessage] not Covariant[SomeMessage.type], because SomeMessage.type (type of the companion object SomeMessage) does not conform to MessageBase.

Strangely, the error goes away without the type annotation, say, `val result = func(message)`, and the type of result is exactly the same as what's meant: Covariant[SomeMessage.Builder]. So it just fails with the correct type annotation. Is this a bug?

One more clue is that this doesn't happen with all Covariant replaced with NonConvariant. So it might somehow be related to covariance. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

---

I know that some little tweaks can be a walkaround for this specific problem here e.g. simply omitting the type annotation might be one of them. But it would be really helpful if I can get more clues on what's really going on in compiler for example by giving some command line options to it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason why also, but to give a slight alternative to @AssafMendelson 's answer, the following works too:

```
trait BuilderBase

trait MessageBase {
  type Builder <: BuilderBase
}
class SomeMessage extends MessageBase {
  type Builder = BuilderBase {}
}

class Covariant[+T]
class NonCovariant[T]
def func[T <: MessageBase](value: Covariant[T]): Covariant[T#Builder] = null

val message: Covariant[SomeMessage] = null
val result: Covariant[SomeMessage#Builder] = func(message)
```

So basically instead of the class definition in the companion object, simply define it in the class

Comment: This can be a walkaround, too. But I don't really want to change the structural design here unless what I've done here is something wrong or not allowed. And if this is really a bug, I'll have to report it to the scala team.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that the compiler gets confused by the type parameter Builder and the class Builder

Basically SomeMessage.Builder can reference both the type inherited and the object, however, it first tries the instance and only then the object.

I tried a simple change: I changed the class builder to builder2 (and the relevant references to it) and it seems to work.

Comment: Well.. looking at the error message, I believe the compiler confused SomeMessage with SomeMessage.type, which is strange, not SomeMessage.Builder with SomeMessage#Builder, which are the same here anyway.